# How should I get an approximation to $(x^n - (x - 1)^n)$?

Tags: calculus, approximation

I'm trying to isolate $n$ in $$\frac{x^n - (x - 1)^n}{x^n} = 0.9.$$

If I take the log in base $x$, I end up with $$\log_x(x^n - (x - 1)^n) - n = \log_x(0.9).$$

Now I don't know how to go on.  Is it time to approximate this expression and move on?  Should I get an approximation?  Thank you.

Comment: Divide the $x^n$ into both pieces of the numerator. It'll work out better.

Answer (score 2):

$$1-(1-x^{-1})^n=0.9$$
so
$$(1-x^{-1})^n=0.1,$$
$$n=\frac{\ln 0.1}{\ln(1-x^{-1})}$$
etc.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{x^n - (x - 1)^n}{x^n} = 0.9 = 1-\left(1-\frac 1x\right)^n = 0.9
$$

then

$$
\left(1-\frac 1x\right)^n = 1-0.9\rightarrow 1-\frac1x = \frac{1}{10^n}
$$

and

$$
x = \frac{10^n-1}{10^n}
$$

or

$$
n = \log_{10}\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)
$$

etc